# MongoDb Aggregation $in over list of collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

```
BasicDBObject matchDBObejct = new BasicDBObject('$match',
            new BasicDBObject("type", ArticleSourceType.MICROBLOGS.toString())
           .append(trackInsightGraphFilterCO.getMetricFeild(), new BasicDBObject('$exists', true).append('$ne', ""))
    )
BasicDBObject groupDBObject = new BasicDBObject('$group', new BasicDBObject("_id", '$' + trackInsightGraphFilterCO.getMetricFeild()).append("total", new BasicDBObject('$sum', 1)))
BasicDBObject limitDBObject = new BasicDBObject('$sort', new BasicDBObject("total", -1))
BasicDBObject sortDbObject = new BasicDBObject('$limit', 10);
List<BasicDBObject> pipeline = [matchDBObejct, groupDBObject, limitDBObject, sortDbObject];
```

My above Query runs fine-
but when i add additional parameter in my match query I got no result.

```
.append("track",new BasicDBObject('$in',tracks))
```

where tracks is list of Track domain .toString();
ie-

```
List<Track> trackDomainObjects;
for(Track track:trackDomainObjects){
tracks.add(track.toString())
}
```

and my match query becomes like this-

```
BasicDBObject matchDBObejct = new BasicDBObject('$match',
            new BasicDBObject("type", ArticleSourceType.MICROBLOGS.toString())
                    .append("track",new BasicDBObject('$in',tracks))
                    .append(trackInsightGraphFilterCO.getMetricFeild(), new BasicDBObject('$exists', true).append('$ne', ""))
    )
```

There is No Exception in console,and I have a data in my Mongo DB.
My below console query is giving me data-

```
db.socialNotification.aggregate([ 
{$match:{"type":"MICROBLOGS","track":{$in:[DBRef('track',ObjectId("57f5fe0ce4b0e960f6d6ab9a")),DBRef('track',ObjectId("57f5fe2be4b0e960f6d6ac42"))]},"authorLocation" : { $exists : true, $ne : "" } }}, 
{ $group: { _id: "$authorLocation", total: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
{$sort:{ total:-1}},
{$limit: 10} ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i read:

```
where tracks is list of Track domain .toString(); ie-
```

But in your working example i see:

```
{$match:{"type":"MICROBLOGS","track":{$in:[DBRef('track',ObjectId("57f5fe0ce4b0e960f6d6ab9a")),DBRef('track',ObjectId("57f5fe2be4b0e960f6d6ac42"))]},"authorLocation" : { $exists : true, $ne : "" } }},
```

In your working example you have a list of ObjectIds.
Make sure that "tracks" in your code is also a **list of ObjectIds**! When you pass a list of strings it will not work